# VBA Excel delete children items

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, parent-child

I am trying to write a macro that would go through the column and see if current cell contains value (reading from left) from the previous row, same column. elow is an example image with yellow cells marked for deleting. For example, there's cell with value "22.2" and next contains that same value and ".1" at the end, meaning that it's a sub-item and needs to be deleted.

[image]

What I have in mind code wise is this:

```
Sub DeleteSubparts()

'Declare variables
 
Dim LastRow As String
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

'Delete parts subgroup

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 10).Value = Left(Cells(i - 1, 10)) Then
Cells(i, 10).Value = ""
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This idea is not really the best approach, but each value in that column "J" is unique and sorted A-z so this idea should work. But general goal is to see if there's a subpart of any part in the list and if so - delete that subpart.

Could someone, please, assist me with finishing that code?

P.S. In my code it just blanks the cell for testing sakes, but there's some problem in how I wrote the code. It returns "Argument not optional" error

EDIT:

Trying something taht seems more correct and doesn't return an error, but still does nothing that's visible nor intended.

```
If Cells(i, 10).Value = Left(Cells(i - 1, 10), Len(Cells(i - 1, 10))) Then
Cells(i, 10).Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: Some thing like `cell.offset(-1,0).value=left(cell.value,len(cell.offset(-1,0))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Says that object is required.

Comment: Error due missing length parameter -> When using Left you need 2 parameters string and length.
If Left("Eduards", 5) = "Eduar" Then...

Comment: Yeah but that length is dynamic and is as long as the previous cell value was

Comment: you will need to use cells(y,x) or look at using a range object called `cell` it wasn't a solution, an idea of where you are going wrong as @bankeris says

Comment: well when add it: Left("Eduards", LEN("Eduards"))  Then...

Comment: I don't understand, there's nowhere my username included.

Comment: You wrote length is dynamic, I just wrote example how to get Length of your string. As in original code I wrote  static 5. If we look forward the code it should work half now. It will make blank only first finding if I'm right.

Comment: Sorry! That's not really helpful. That "Eduards" means nothing to me and I'm still confused, even more than I was originally

Comment: The `Len()` function will return a numeric value of the length of it's parameter. For example; `LEN("Eduards")` (your name) would return the value `7` because the length of your username is 7 characters long. The short story is, the `LEN()` function will allow you to use a dynamic value, you just need to pass the previous cells value through it :)

Comment: What would be the code I'm looking for then? Because If Cells(i, 10).Value = Left(Cells(i - 1, 10), Len(Cells(i, 10))) Then
Cells(i, 10).Value = ""
End If doesn't do a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete the entire row containing the "child" cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim row As Long
    Const col As Integer = 10 ' col J

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        ' Start on second row of data
        row = 2
        
        Do While .Cells(row, col).Value <> ""
        
            ' Use Like to compare the value of the current cell to the value of the previous cell
            If .Cells(row, col).Value Like .Cells(row - 1, col).Value & ".*" Then
                .Rows(row).Delete
            Else
                row = row + 1
            End If
        Loop
        
    End With

End Sub
```

or this will just clear the child cell contents.

```
    If .Cells(row, col).Value Like .Cells(row - 1, col).Value & ".*" Then
        .Cells(row, col).Clear
    End If
    row = row + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! But it says that there's an invalid procedure call or argument in the line
 Do While .Cells("J" & row).Value <> ""

Comment: Fixed it. Try it now.